# Git url mapping to custom domain

Tags: go

How to map github url to custom domain?

Example:

I saw below url mapping

> go get github.com/goji/goji

to this url?

> go get goji.io

Do they host a replica or DNS redirection?

In golang, we import repositories using url path. If we use a custom domain,
we need not rewrite import paths when we change repository hosting, say from github.com to bitbucket or vice-versa

So how to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](https://elithrar.github.io/article/custom-import-urls-github-pages-jekyll/) seems to explain the process.  The short version is:

1. Set up a CNAME for your custom domain.
2. Add special HTML markup to your web page.

Comment: These two meta tags does the trick. 

<meta name="go-import" content="goji.io git https://github.com/goji/goji">

<meta name="go-source" content="goji.io https://github.com/goji/goji/ https://github.com/goji/goji/tree/master{/dir} https://github.com/goji/goji/blob/master{/dir}/{file}#L{line}"> 

go-source tag is for GoDoc